# bad operand types for binary operator %

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm practicing my java and have run into some problems.

I want to learn to remove elements from an Arraylist, so I'm removing the odds.

```
    public static void arrayLists(){
        List<Integer> xlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x ++){
            xlist.add(x);
        }
        for (Iterator<Integer> pointer = xlist.iterator(); pointer.hasNext();){
            if (pointer % 2 == 1){
                pointer.remove();
            }
        }
     }
```

Why doesn't this compile? 'bad operand types for binary operator %'

I think the issue has to do with the elements of the list are Integers while I'm comparing them to int (s). Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: pointer is of type `Iterator` and not `Integer`. You need to extract the Integer value first to call % on it

Comment: @Mhsmith21 answer posted

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
        if (pointer.next() % 2 == 1){
            pointer.remove();
        }
```

pointer is the `Iterator`, and you can't perform % on it. You have to get the integer at the current location of the `Ierator` by calling `pointer.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if (pointer % 2 == 1)
```

with

```
if (pointer.next() % 2 == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code , working code would be:-

```
public static void arrayLists(){
   List<Integer> xlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){ //this is not a compiler error but avoid unnecassary spaces , x ++ should be x++
      xlist.add(x);
      }
   Iterator<Integer> pointer = xlist.iterator(); // write this out of the for loop statement, since we wont be needing it
   while(pointer.hasNext()){ //its better to use while loop, since there is no increment for counter variable required, the iterator will do that job
      if (pointer.next() % 2 == 1){ //get current element in iterator by using next() function, pointer.next()
        pointer.remove();
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

changes done -  `if (pointer.next() % 2 == 1)` . `.next` will actually return the object
    public class Test {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arrayLists();
    }

    public static void arrayLists() {
        List<Integer> xlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; x++) {
            xlist.add(x);
        }
        for (Iterator<Integer> pointer = xlist.iterator() ; pointer.hasNext() ;) {
            if (pointer.next() % 2 == 1) {
                pointer.remove();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(xlist);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```